# Run command in the environment of a specific systemd service

Tags: systemd

Quite commonly I stumble over issues where a command yields different results, depending wether being run in my user shell or as part of a Systemd service, e.g. via `ExecStart`.

Is there any way to run a command in a shell that mimics that of a specific Systemd service, e.g. `dhcpcd.service` as close as possible? Having the same capabilities, env variables and resources available would be a start.

In my current issue I have a hard time replicating the behaviour of `ip link` in `ExectStart` of my `dhcpcd.service`. But this would be super useful in general for debugging systemd services.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `systemd-run`:

```
# systemd-run ip link                                           
Running as unit: run-r2723175b10a543f38faddda99baa8ca3.service
# journalctl -u run-r2723175b10a543f38faddda99baa8ca3.service
-- Logs begin at Fri 2020-09-11 23:45:32 CEST, end at Fri 2020-09-18 15:33:51 CEST. --
Sep 18 15:33:51 w systemd[1]: Started /usr/bin/ip link.
Sep 18 15:33:51 w ip[3904]: 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
...
```

Use `-E` and other flags to 'mimic' the environment of your service.

Comment: Thanks, I already discovered systemd-run. Please note, that running it in the environment of a *specific* service is important for me. Afaict this is not supported by systemd-run.

Comment: Do you want to run the command in the environment of a running service or mimic that environment?

Comment: I don't know what would be the difference.
Just setting every environment variable doesn't solve my problem. There is more that influences the behaviour of the service, e.g. as I wrote in the question, kernel capabilities, OS resources, also systemd slice and cgroup.
If systemd-run had a flag like `--like-service=<servicename>`, it'd be happy. But apparently that is not the case.